# Jasper with Hibernate - entity class not found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jasper-reports, hql

i'm trying to create a jasper with hibernate connection as demonstrated in the tutorial   **http://www.tutorialcenters.com/index.php/how-to-design-report-using-jasperreport-hibernate-connection/**

i did exactly as specified in the tutorial but when i'm getting 
***`entity class not found: mappings.EmployeeMaster`***

can anyone please tell me some solution for this....

**my samplehiber project structure in netbeans IDE**  - **[CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXLPd.png)**

[image]

**Setting Classpath** - [**CLICK**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byuB1.png)

[image: Setting Classpath]

**Connection setup with MySQL Database using hibernate Configuration**  - [**CLICK**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysH4y.png)

[image]

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hse</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="mappings/EmployeeMaster.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="hse"/>
  <table-filter match-name="employee_master"/>

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**EmployeeMaster.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 15, 2013 11:07:05 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="mappings.EmployeeMaster" table="employee_master" catalog="hse">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="userCode" type="string">
            <column name="user_code" length="60" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="first_name" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="last_name" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="deptId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="dept_id" />
        </property>
        <property name="designationId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="designation_id" />
        </property>
        <property name="empEmail" type="string">
            <column name="emp_email" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="created_date" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="modified_date" length="19" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**EmployeeMaster.java**

```
package mappings;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class EmployeeMaster  implements java.io.Serializable {


         private Integer id;
         private String userCode;
         private String firstName;
         private String lastName;
         private Integer deptId;
         private Integer designationId;
         private String empEmail;
         private String status;
         private Date createdDate;
         private Date modifiedDate;

        public EmployeeMaster() {
        }


        public EmployeeMaster(String userCode) {
            this.userCode = userCode;
        }
        public EmployeeMaster(String userCode, String firstName, String lastName, Integer deptId, Integer designationId, String empEmail, String status, Date createdDate, Date modifiedDate) {
           this.userCode = userCode;
           this.firstName = firstName;
           this.lastName = lastName;
           this.deptId = deptId;
           this.designationId = designationId;
           this.empEmail = empEmail;
           this.status = status;
           this.createdDate = createdDate;
           this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getUserCode() {
            return this.userCode;
        }

        public void setUserCode(String userCode) {
            this.userCode = userCode;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public Integer getDeptId() {
            return this.deptId;
        }

        public void setDeptId(Integer deptId) {
            this.deptId = deptId;
        }
        public Integer getDesignationId() {
            return this.designationId;
        }

        public void setDesignationId(Integer designationId) {
            this.designationId = designationId;
        }
        public String getEmpEmail() {
            return this.empEmail;
        }

        public void setEmpEmail(String empEmail) {
            this.empEmail = empEmail;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return this.status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        public Date getCreatedDate() {
            return this.createdDate;
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }
        public Date getModifiedDate() {
            return this.modifiedDate;
        }

        public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
            this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        }
    }
```

**IDE Log**

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: mappings.EmployeeMaster
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:457)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JRHibernateConnection.getSessionFactory(JRHibernateConnection.java:130)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JRHibernateConnection$1.run(JRHibernateConnection.java:157)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
        at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1013)
        at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionsDialog.jButtonNewParameterActionPerformed(ConnectionsDialog.java:578)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionsDialog.access$400(ConnectionsDialog.java:47)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionsDialog$7.actionPerformed(ConnectionsDialog.java:221)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
        at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1013)
        at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionsDialog.setVisible(ConnectionsDialog.java:651)
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.menu.DatasourcesAction.performAction(DatasourcesAction.java:46)
        at org.openide.util.actions.CallableSystemAction$1.run(CallableSystemAction.java:118)
        at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.ActionsBridge.doPerformAction(ActionsBridge.java:77)
        at org.openide.util.actions.CallableSystemAction.actionPerformed(CallableSystemAction.java:114)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at org.openide.awt.ToolbarButton.processMouseEvent(ToolbarButton.java:61)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mappings.EmployeeMaster
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:119)
        ... 123 more
```

Comment: As I can see that you are using mysql database and want to connect with hibernate connection. Connect your database with mysql.

Comment: sir but i need hibernate connection in my jasper report..............

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql........

Comment: Then connect your database with mysql not with hibernate connection. try it once then tell me.

Comment: but i'm using hibernate framework to connect to mysql.....so how can i connect hibernate in jasper.....i'm not getting it to be done as demonstrated in that tutorial (http://www.tutorialcenters.com/index.php/how-to-design-report-using-jasperreport-hibernate-connection/)

Comment: if i connect and generate jasper report with mysql query.......then what's the use of hibernate.....since i'm using hibernate framework....i've generated jasper report using normal mysql queries

Comment: can you please edit your question and add action where you write hibernate query, and how you want to connect it with jasper server.

Comment: @user1791574 i did'nt get u sir.....

Comment: which framework you are using for your code? e.g: struts , ejb or something else?

Comment: i'm using struts2.............. and hibernate for handling backhand database....

Comment: sir @user1791574 any solutions for this

Comment: Please add the contents of `EmployeeMaster.java`

Answer (score 4):

You are pointing Jasper at the source files.   Jasper wants a jar or the class files.   Build your project in Netbeans and watch the output for the jar location.

Usually Netbeans build the jar into the project's dist directory (samplehiber/dist/samplehiber.jar).  That is what you need to put on the Jasper classpath.

If you want to use class files, point Jasper at your samplehiber/build/classes directory.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an **`EmployeeMaster.class`** file in your classpath. Make sure you rebuild your project. See where your tool is building your `.class` files and add directory that to your classpath.

Comment: @user2040500 And is there an `EmployeeMaster.class` file in your `c:\Users\Work\Desktop\samplehiber\src\java\mappings` directory?

Comment: @user2040500 you can try removing `c:\Users\Work\Desktop\samplehiber\src\java\mappings` from the classpath, leaving only `c:\Users\Work\Desktop\samplehiber\src\java`

Comment: yes i did that but still the same error......entity class not found: mappings.EmployeeMaster

Comment: you need an **EmployeeMaster.class** file in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a similar approach to what you did in the past. Turns out for whatever reason hibernate can't see its own xml files inside packages.

For the sake if simplicity have you tried moving the EmployeeMaster.hbm.xml to the root folder of your source? i.e. .\src or .\src\java (not exactly sure which is which in netbeans)

It worked for me. But do note my issue happened in eclipse so it may or may not apply to this issue. It's worth a shot though. "If all else fails, keep the set up simple." That's what I always say to eliminate other factors. :)